# Check if all tuples in a list are different (ECLiPSe)

Tags: list, prolog, tuples

I have a list with tuples like this:

```
[(1,2),(5,3),(6,7)]
```

I'm trying to write a predicate that checks if all tuples in a list are different. The following line works for a list with integers but not for a list with tuples:

```
all_diff(L) :- \+ (select(X,L,R),member(X,R)).
```

`member/2` works fine to check if a tuple is in a list but it is the `select/3` that has problems with tuples. It gives a type error.

How do I check if all tuples are different?

Comment: [`select/3`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#select) gives a type error? When?

Comment: @false For example when I try the following query `select((1, 2), [(1, 3), (1, 2)], R).` .

Comment: What Prolog interpreter are you using? GNU? SWI? Other? Can you explain why it doesn't work? The code works as you have it written as far as I can tell.

Comment: Neither SICStus, nor SWI, nor GNU produce an error for that query!

Comment: @false I'm using ECLiPSe 6.1, that will be it. Still don't understand why it wouldn't work in ECLiPSe.

Comment: @lurker TkEclipse is what I'm using.

Comment: @lurker: Stanko talks about ECLiPSe Constraint Logic Programming System. And YES! Stanko is right! in that system this is a file-related operation. My recommendation: use one of the systems above.

Comment: @false ah sorry about that. Overloaded product names... :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@false pointed out that `select/3` does not work in ECLiPSe because in that system it is a file-related operation.

I want to keep using the same system so I wrote a select for tuples:

```
%Given a list of tuples this checks if they are all different
allDiffTuples(L) :- \+ (selectTuple(X,L,R),member(X,R)).

selectTuple((A,B),[(A,B)|T],T).
selectTuple((A,B),[H|T],[H|R]) :-
    selectTuple((A,B),T,R).
```

Comment: Why be so specific? Why not write your own more general `select_element/3` that would work with lists of anything? Then it will be more useful. :) Just replace all `(A,B)` in your code with `X`.